# How to redirect multiple URLs dynamically with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect each link/URL like `https://example.com/blogspot/good-url` to `https://example.com/blog/good-url`

In all links I just want to replace `blogspot` with `blog` Is this something we can achieve through `.htaccess`?

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/blogspot/$  https://example.com/blog/$
```

also tried the below but doesn't seems to work:

```
RewriteRule ^/?blogspot/(.*)$ https://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a simple `Redirect` for this

```
Redirect 302 /blogspot/ https://example.com/blog/
```

This will redirect all URLs from `/blogspot/foobar` to `/blog/foobar` .

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I needed!